# Callback beforeDelete in Model CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php

```
    protected $allowCallbacks = true;
    protected $beforeDelete   = ['setDeletedBy'];

    protected function setDeletedBy($id, $purge)
    {
        $this->update($id, ['deleted_by' => user_id()]);

        return [$id, $purge];
    }
```

How to update beforeDelete in CI4. Especially when you want to update data in the same table. My code above doesn't work

Solution to that problem